# Add a null value column in Spark Data Frame using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and want to add a column of type `String` with null values. 
How can it be done using Spark Java API.

I used `lit` functions, but getting error when tried writing the DF and `saveAsTable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was able to solve by using lit function on the column with null value and type cast the column to String type.

```
df.withColumn(
 "col_name", functions.lit(null)
).withColumn("col_name", 
  df.col("channel_name").cast(DataTypes.StringType)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df.withColumn("col_name", lit(null).cast("string"))
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType

df.withColumn("col_name", lit(null).cast(StringType))
```

Comment: Thank you for year answer; could maybe elaborate a bit more on why this resolves the question?